# Heroku Login Error. "No such file or directory (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git, heroku

I am very new to Ruby, Git, and Heroku and I am trying to get everything setup on my Window 7 machine. The first error was easily fixable by editing a couple heroku files to include the rest-client gem, but now I get this error and I can't figure it out using the "google it" method:

```
C:\rails\first_app>heroku login
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: foo
Password (typing will be hidden): C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `init
ialize': No such file or directory (LoadError)
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `dlopen'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:19
7:in `new'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:19
7:in `ask_for_password_on_windows'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:18
7:in `ask_for_credentials'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:22
1:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84
:in `get_credentials'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41
:in `login'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/command/au
th.rb:31:in `login'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/command.rb
:213:in `run'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:
in `start'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-3.0.1/bin/heroku:17:in `<to
p (required)>'
        from C:/ruby/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
        from C:/ruby/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

It is the 64-bit version of ruby 2.0.0.

Hmm, i guess I will have to install the 32-bit version until this issue is fixed. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/834 Did you have 64 or 32 bit ruby?

Comment: what the hell is this issue got the same thing how to solve this it just a simple login wtf

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're running Ruby 2. I had the same problem.

I copy-paste my answer from here : [Heroku Login failed using Windows CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740168/heroku-login-failed-using-windows-cli/28746733#28746733)

I was having the same problem when using "heroku login" command from outside the install dir, because it used my Ruby 2.1 installation as explained by @kdmcclin.

```
C:\>heroku login
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxxxx@xxxxxxx.net
Password (typing will be hidden): C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `initialize': No such file or directory (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `dlopen'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/Win32API.rb:14:in `initialize'
    ...
```

But if you go first to install dir and then "bin", the command works fine :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxxxx@xxxxxxx.net
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```

But, we have to run the command from our project dir. So what I did is changing the PATH system variable in order to have Heroku/bin path before Ruby2.1.

Old PATH :

```
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;[...Otherstuff...];C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd
```

New PATH :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;[...Otherstuff...];C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd
```

And now it's working :

```
C:\ProjectDir>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxxxx@xxxxxxx.net
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```